# Using Liquibase to insert data from remote database

Tags: java, database, liquibase

I know that the primary use for Liquibase is to manipulate data or make changes for a specific schema.

But I want to know if there is a way to use Liquibase to migrate data from a remote DB to a local DB and validate the data in the process by using maybe the liquibase/change/custom/CustomTaskChange interface?

Answer (score 1):

While you can use a hammer to put in a screw, it is not the best tool for the job. Likewise, while you could conceivably use Liquibase for data migration, there are other tools that are better suited for that task. I would look at things like the Community (i.e. open source and free as in beer) Pentaho ETL suite.

http://community.pentaho.com/